# Array to string error using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

This code was given to me by a friend and works perfectly, however in my system it Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\web2\database.php on line 90 and on line 91

```
     function edit($table, $id)
        {
             $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  `COLUMN_NAME` 
            FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
            WHERE  `TABLE_NAME` =  '$table'";

      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

            $header = $this->dbLocalhost->query($query);

            foreach($header as $data) {
                echo "<p>";
    90.         echo "".$data.": ";
    91.         echo "<input type='text' name=".$data." />";    
                echo "</p>";
            }

            echo "<input type='submit' name='Insert' />";

            echo "</form>";
}
```

sorry to ask, as I have the irritating feeling its very simple.
Thanks

Comment: Your $data variable is an array, before line #90 do a print_r($data) and use the proper key like $data[key], my guess is that you need to use $data['COLUMN_NAME']

Comment: Thanks I changed $data to $data['COLUMN_NAME'] without using print_r($data) to give the desired outcome.

Comment: Your friend hates you ;)

Comment: Also add a "where" on table_schema column, otherwise you could end up with tables from different databases.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks I changed $data to $data['COLUMN_NAME'] without using print_r($data) to give the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT  `COLUMN_NAME` FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE  `TABLE_NAME` =  '".$table."'";
$cols = mysql_query($q);
while ($col = mysql_fetch_object($cols)) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo ucfirst($col->COLUMN_NAME);
    echo "<input type='text' name=".$col->COLUMN_NAME." />";    
    echo "</p>";
}
```

Output will be something like

```
<p>Id<input type="text" name="id"></p>
<p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p><!--and more-->
```